# jQuery fadeIn & hide script

Tags: jquery, hide, fadein

I'm not very familiar with jQuery so if someone can check this script for me and point out the problem if you see it, it would be greatly appreciated.

The script is for a tab menu that hides and fades in elements on the page. I have created an additional div that needs to remain outside .my_account_orders, but needs to fadein and hide with the orders menu.

```
if(avada_myaccount_active.hasClass('downloads') ) {

        jQuery('.avada-myaccount-data .digital-downloads').fadeIn();

    } else if(avada_myaccount_active.hasClass('orders') ) {

        jQuery('.avada-myaccount-data .my_account_orders').fadeIn();
        jQuery('.paging-nav').fadeIn(); //Need this to fade in

    } else if(avada_myaccount_active.hasClass('address') ) {

        jQuery('.avada-myaccount-data .myaccount_address, .avada-myaccount-data .address').fadeIn();

    } else if(avada_myaccount_active ) {

        jQuery('.avada-myaccount-data .edit-account-form, .avada-myaccount-data .edit-account-heading').fadeIn();

        jQuery('.avada-myaccount-data h2:nth-of-type(1)').hide();
        jQuery('.paging-nav').hide(); //Need this to be hidden

    }
```

I have commented the lines I added with .pagin-nav which is the div I created that needs to have the same state changes as orders. At the moment .paging-nav is always visible. Hopefully it's just a simple syntax error on my part, thanks in advance.

**Solved**

Comment: what does `avada_myaccount_active` stands for? Is it a variable declared beforehand? And why do you have `else if(avada_myaccount_active )` without condition?

Comment: @Raoulito This is a script from the main.js file from the Avada wordpress theme. There are conditional menu classes assigned to active so the page knows what to display and what to hide. I only added the two commented lines to the existing and functioning script. I'm just trying to give .paging-nav the same functionality as .my_account_orders

Comment: @Raoulito the last else if statement is actually a shorthand condition to check the existence of that element

Comment: @nickyb can you provide your HTML related to your problem?

Comment: @Enrico I found a solution to my problem using an entirely different script. Thanks for your time and reaching out.